# Problemas com lógica para trazer dados de uma lista ou tabela

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Fiz vários posts aqui e resolvi quase todos os problemas. Porem entendi que o problema estava na lógica que eu montei para trazer o resultado. Sei que eu estou perguntando bastante, mas estou tentando e percebo que falta algo mais em mim para resolver a questão.

Tenho uma `linq` que me trás tudo que eu preciso. Porem da forma que vem, não consigo montar minha tela.

Aí, após vários posts e orientações aqui e em outro site, disseram-me que eu exportasse listas separadas para cada situação pretendida. Aí que eu me perdi todo e peço ajuda a vocês.

### Meu cenário é esse:

A primeira `linq`, me trás todas as informações do meu banco, seguindo alguns critérios.

Para cada Motivo, eu trago uma lista de UN. Cada UN uma lista de Família e assim vai.

Quando eu fiz a segunda `linq` para buscar a UN referente a cada Motivo, **foi aí que percebi que estava errado**. Falta algo que não consigo encaixar.

Consegui fazer com que os Motivos e as UN não se repetisse. **Mas não consigo listar as UN referentes ao Motivo correspondente.**

Na `linq` UN, eu peguei da tabela Apresentação e essa tabela não se relaciona com a Motivo e por isso o problema.

Abaixo as `linq`:

A primeira trás tudo e a segunda tentativa de trazer as UN relativas a cada Motivo. Não deu certo.

Minha linq(tudo):

```
var monta_arvore = db.Ruptura
       .Where(m => m.IDMotivo != 7)
       .Select(rup => new MontaArvoreAcao
       {
           IDRuptura = rup.IDRuptura,
           DataRuptura = rup.DataRuptura,
           IDMotivo = rup.IDMotivo,
           Motivo = rup.Motivo.Motivo1,
           IDOrigem = rup.IDOrigem,
           CodigoPDV = rup.CodigoPDV,
           UF = rup.PDV.UF,
           Cidade = rup.PDV.Cidade,
           CnpjDescricao = rup.PDV.Cnpj + " - " + rup.PDV.Descricao,
           Codigo_Apresentacao = rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
           Unidade_Negocio = rup.Apresentacao.Unidade_Negocio,
           Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = rup.Apresentacao.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio,
           Franquia = rup.Apresentacao.Franquia,
           Familia = rup.Apresentacao.Familia,
           Descricao = rup.Apresentacao.Descricao

       }).ToList().OrderBy(r => r.IDMotivo);
```

Minha linq UN:

```
foreach (var _idmotivo in monta_arvore)
{
    _listaUnidade = db.Apresentacao
        .GroupBy(g => new { Codigo = g.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio, UN = g.Unidade_Negocio})
        .Where(un => un.Key.Codigo != "0")
        .Select(u => new MontaArvoreAcao
        {
            Unidade_Negocio = u.Select(s => s.Unidade_Negocio).FirstOrDefault(),
            Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = u.Key.Codigo
        })
        .ToList()
        .OrderBy(o => o.Unidade_Negocio);
}
```

Veja que realmente não dá certo, da forma que está.

Comment: Acho que você poderia estruturar melhor seu texto, pois está muito confuso. Utilizar marcadores, quebra de linhas.

Comment: Um texto menor, talvez eu não consigo passar a minha dúvida, dar a maior quantidade de subsídio possível para a solução.

Comment: Acho que deveria percorrer monta_arvore e ir relacionando as UN, certo? Vou por esse caminho e ver o que acontece.

Comment: Quer uma dica infalivel? faz as query no SQL... teste... depois "traduza" para o linq. Utilize o programa LINQPad que ira te ajudar tambem.

Answer (score 1):

Eu juro que não entendi muito sua pergunta, porem irei responde para tentar te ajudar... (não sou tao familiarizado com Linq)

```
List<UN> ListaUN;//carrega a lista de UN do banco.

foreach (var _idmotivo in monta_arvore)
{
    var listaUnidade = ListaUN.Where(x => x.IDMotivo == _idmotivo.IDMotivo);
    //seria isso?
}
```

Se for uma lista interna dele(que acredito que e seu caso), pode fazer assim tambem:

```
Apresentacao.Where(x => x.ListaUN.All(s => s.IDMotivo == _udmotivo.IDMotivo)));
```

Por favor deixe um comentario!

Comment: resolvi aqui. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33694/linq-tr%C3%A1s-resultado-mas-n%C3%A3o-obedece-ao-join