# Linq trás resultado, mas não obedece ao join

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Estamos chegando perto. Com esse código, quase funcionou. Aí troquei o *`Distinct()`* para *`DistinctBy()`* e não repetiu, mas continua não obedecendo o *`IDMotivo`*. O que vem na *linq* não condiz com a *query*. Em todos os Motivos eu trouxe ***3 UN's***, sendo que no Motivo de `ID=4`, eu deveria ter apenas ***2 UN's***, o que parece que ele está trazendo a mesma informação, independente do *`IDMotivo`*.

Estou aqui tentando uma solução. Veja como ficou meu código:

```cs
public static List<MontaArvoreAcao> CriarListaArvoreAcao()
{
    RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

    var _listaUnidade = (
        from r in db.Ruptura
        join a in db.Apresentacao on r.Codigo_Apresentacao equals (a.Codigo_Apresentacao)
        join m in db.Motivo on r.IDMotivo equals (m.IDMotivo)
        where r.IDMotivo != 6
        group r by new { a.Unidade_Negocio, r.IDMotivo } into gr
        select new MontaArvoreAcao
        {
            IDMotivo = gr.Key.IDMotivo,
            Unidade_Negocio = gr.Key.Unidade_Negocio
        }).DistinctBy(u => u.Unidade_Negocio)
          .DistinctBy(m => m.IDMotivo)
          .ToList().OrderBy(r => r.IDMotivo);

    return _listaUnidade.ToList();
}
```

Da forma como está, sem o *`DistinctBy`*, eu consigo trazer todas as ***UN's***. Trazendo uma leitura das ***UN's*** assim:

```
{GENÉRICOS,MIP,DERMOCOSMÉTICOS},
{DERMOCOSMÉTICOS,MIP,GENÉRICOS},
{MIP,GENÉRICOS,DERMOCOSMÉTICOS},
{DERMOCOSMÉTICOS,GENÉRICOS},
{MIP,GENÉRICOS,DERMOCOSMÉTICOS}
```

Para os respectivos Motivos:

```
{VENDEU TODO ESTOQUE},
{PRODUTO EM FALTA NO CENTRO DE DISTRIBUIÇÃO},
{PRODUTO NÃO CADASTRADO NA CENTRAL},
{PRODUTO INATIVO},
{PRODUTO CADASTRADO / SOB ENCOMENDA}
```

Que representam respectivamente os **ID's: 1,2,3 e 4**.
Veja que me trouxe conforme a ***query***, mas não consigo fazer uma redistribuição para cada Motivo.

**Como é minha tela**:

A minha tela cria os primeiro nó com os `checkbox` referentes a cada `Motivo`. Os motivos estão listados corretamente e os `checkbox` são criados corretamente.

Aí quando eu vou listar as UN's, cada qual em baixo dos seus motivo correspondente, é que não funciona adequadamente, ou seja, para cada Motivo criado na página, eu listo todos esses Motivos de uma vez para cada Motivo.

O correto é listar, para cada `Motivo`, as `UN's` correspondentes. Pode ser que falta alguma coisa, algum ID, mas qual?

Cheguei a um ponto em não saber mais nada. Deveria ser um `Distinct` para um `ID` apropriado, mas como eu faço isso? Essa é minha dúvida cruel que eu estou passando.

Mas dessa forma trouxe todos corretamente. O que falta é a distribuição correta para cada `Motivo` correspondente. No aguardo e obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido. Fiz a diferenciação na própria View e agora funcionou. Veja como foi:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (_motivo != @item.Motivo)
        {
            _idmotivo = @item.IDMotivo;
            <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                @item.Motivo
                <ul>
                    @foreach(var un in (List<Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao>) ViewData["ListaUn"])
                    {
                        if (@un.IDMotivo == @item.IDMotivo)==> ***aqui resolveu***
                        { 
                            <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                @un.Unidade_Negocio
                            </li>
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
        _motivo = @item.Motivo;
    }
</ul>
```